# Notification vibrates on each progress update

Tags: android, notifications

When on Android 8.0 (Oreo), every time there is an update to the progress of the notification, it vibrates. So the phone vibrates 100 times in the process. This only happens on Android 8.0 So i can assume I am having some improper use of their API. I am asking for help in stopping the vibration on each progress update of the notification. Here is my code:

Building Notification

```
mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) createChannel(mNotifyManager);
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mActivity, "FileDownload")
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.colorNotification))
        .setContentTitle(mFile.getName())
        .setContentText(mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setProgress(0, 0, true);
mNotifyManager.notify(mFile.getId().hashCode(), mBuilder.build());
```

Create Channel method

```
  @TargetApi(26)
  private void createChannel(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
    String name = "FileDownload";
    String description = "Notifications for download status";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX;

    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(name, name, importance);
    mChannel.setDescription(description);
    mChannel.enableLights(true);
    mChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
  }
```

onProgress

```
  @Override
  public void onProgress(File file, double progress, long downloadedBytes, long totalBytes) {
    mBuilder.setProgress(100, (int) (progress * 100), false);
    mNotifyManager.notify(file.getId().hashCode(), mBuilder.build());
  }
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#enableVibration(boolean)

Comment: @CommonsWare this doesn't work

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what "doesn't work" means in this context?

Comment: @CommonsWare settings enableVibration(false) does not stop the vibrating

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Using `setOnlyAlertOnce(true)` on your `NotificationCompat.Builder` when initially building the notification should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable vibration like this :

```
notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHT | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                   .setVibrate(new long[]{0L});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set `.setNotificationSilent()` on your update notifications.